# Undefined control sequence problem with \pstree

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

I installed the latest MikTex2.9 and tested the following simple code trying to create a node in a tree diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}
\begin{document}
\pstree[radius=3pt]{\Tcircle{X}}
\end{document}
```

But I received the following error:

```
"Undefined controlled sequence. \pstree[radius=3pt]{\Tcircle{X}}"
```

Any hints what went wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first error is most likely the usage of `pdftex` instead of `latex` or `xelatex`.

This can be fixed with `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`, if `--shell-escape` is enabled (i.e. the `\write18` feature)

The `\pstree` command needs at least the start node (*root*) and a successor node, which is missing in the above document. I just choose `\TC*` for example, i.e. the syntax is

```
\pstree[options]{root}{successor}
```

Of course, `{successor}` can be left empty, but that's no tree actually ;-)

Here's the working document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\pstree[radius=3pt]{\Tcircle{X}}{\TC*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Chrisstian Hupfer: May be you should add it's necessary to use use the --enable-write18 or -shell-escape switch to make it work. Also, it is enough to load `pst-tree`, as it loads the  first  two packages.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks, I've added your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least an empty node where the root points to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\begin{document}
    \pstree[radius=3pt]{\Tcircle{X}}{}
\end{document}
```